# Google Survey Reviews popup iframe through Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to click a button from 'Google Customer Reviews' popup from Puppeteer, and almost out of luck to find a solution. The popup survey is imbedded into a website, and don't know how to select. Without clicking the button, can't proceed next steps since the frame itself is focused. (can't select the main page) I have tried a couple of solutions from multiple resources so far. For example, find selector from nested frames and pages. Looks like it's a dynamic javascript, so that can't select the frame by name or id. The following is a snip of codes.
[Debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S0k8.png)
[Google Customer Reviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfeHT.png)

```
await page.waitForSelector('iframe')
const frameHandle = await page.$( 'iframe[src^="https://www.google.com/shopping/customerreviews"]')
await frame.waitForSelector(GOOGLE_SURVEY_SELECTOR, { visible: true })
await frame.click(GOOGLE_SURVEY_SELECTOR)
```

Any helps or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Found out a clue why it's hard to select the frame. Used a debug tool and added an additional code with following. `const frame = await page.mainFrame().childFrames()` which returns an array of frames. But, still can't figure out how to filter. Do I need to loop through each frame and search or is there other way to filter the frame? Let's say the frame has an ID starting with 'I0_'

Comment: `const googleFrame = frames.find((frame) => {
      return frame.url().includes("https://www.google.com/shopping");
    });` Looks like it can detect the frame with the filter. However, get an another error with "errorMessage": "waitForFunction failed: frame got detached."

Comment: Found a solution for this 'waitForFunction' failed with frame got detached. There were missing keyword 'await' in front of frames.find. After adding the keyword, it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of trying, I did this)

If your problem is that the puppeteer does not see the pop-up element (for example, google `c-wiz` element), this means that the pop-up is another page embedded in the current site (latent iframe).

There are some ways to access it:

1. `const popUpFrame = page.mainFrame().childFrames().filter((frame) => // any page interface check)`
2. `const popUpFrame = page.frames().filter((frame) => // condition)`
3. `const popUpFrame = page.frames()[0].childFrames().filter((frame) => //condition)`

Thanks [Joonyoung Park](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14629841/joonyoung-park)

Have a good hunting!